# Select Svg Path by fill color with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I would like to not display all the white fill paths in my svg.

Imagine an svg with this structure:

```
<svg>
     <path class="pathok"fill="rgb(29,233, 182)"/>
     <path class="pathok" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
     <path class="pathok" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
     <path class="pathok" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)"/> 
</svg>
```

I've tried with this but isn't working:

```
<script>
   if ($("path").attr("fill") == ("rgb(255, 255, 255)")) {
        $(this).css("display","none")
   }
</script>
```

Generally, How I could select tags by the value of his attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is getting all of the paths, not an individual path.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $paths = $('path'); // Get all paths
    for (var i=0;i<$paths.length;i++){ // Iterate through each one
        var $path =$($paths[i]); // This gets a single path
        if ($path.attr("fill") == ("rgb(255, 255, 255)")) {
            $path.css("display","none");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah sure. `i` is used as an 'index' or a 'counter'. We need a counter to keep track of where we are in the `for...` loop, because we use the counter to access the current item in the `$paths` object (i.e. $paths[i]). Every time the for loop iterates (loops around) `i` is increased by 1 (this is done by `i++`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why iterate at all when you can just select the ones you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can just select the elements you want directly, no loops are required.

I've used rect elements rather than paths as you didn't supply and d attributes but the principle is the same.

```js
$("rect[fill='rgb(255, 255, 255)']").css('display', "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
     <rect width="90" height="30" fill="black"/>
     <rect width="10" height="10" x="10" y="10" fill="rgb(29,233, 182)"/>
     <rect width="10" height="10" x="30" y="10" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
     <rect width="10" height="10" x="50" y="10" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
     <rect width="10" height="10" x="70" y="10" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)"/> 
</svg>
```